# Generate Django Password

Tags: django, password-hash

In my PostgreSQL, there is a password column, which has passwords stored in the format

```
argon2$argon2i$v=19$m=512,t=2,p=2$Z1BlYkltRjNhakFE$1cgxZNRetdjoCYwBrjAICA
```

Is there a way to generate this password manually? I am not a backend developer and hence not much idea about how these things are usually handled.

Thanks

Comment: You will need to provide more information. The password will be hashed by the Django code.

Comment: Docs for [Using Argon2 with Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/passwords/#using-argon2-with-django)

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry completely new to all these. My requirement is: I have a Postgres DB and I need to import `users` into it. Each user will have a username and password. If a user is created by using API calls, it looks like the one in the question. I am trying to generate a password for 100+ users so that I can directly import them using a CSV file

Comment: You will need to do that with Django code, rather than inserting directly into the database.

Comment: I was able to achieve what I wanted. I had to start a virtual environment, install django in there. Install argon2. Start shell and run make_password. That did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`make_password`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password) function:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

make_password('abc123')
```

But if you want to change password for a user, then use this(copy pasted from [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords)):

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> u = User.objects.get(username='john')
>>> u.set_password('new password')
>>> u.save()
```

Adding the below code in the Setting.py will help generate Argon2 passwords:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
]
```

You can install argon by `pip install django[argon2]`

Comment: Will this code work in any IDE or do I have to run this code from somewhere else?  Sorry, completely new to these things. Because I get the error `No module named django.contrib.auth.hashers`

Comment: you can use [django shell](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#shell) to test out the code.

Comment: I was able to achieve what I wanted. I had to start a virtual environment, install django in there. Install argon2. Start shell and run make_password. That did the trick.

Comment: I accepted the answer... maybe you could add in the argon part as well... Considering that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the built in function 
**https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager.make_random_password**

```
for user in new_users:
    password = User.objects.make_random_password()
    user.set_password(password)
```

Also notice that make_random_password() accepts keyword arguments `length` and `allowed_chars`